# Barman не видит сервер

Tags: postgresql, debian

Проверяю работу barman локально. Требуется сделать бекап c кластера Postgres локально, то есть где СУБД там и бекап. Barman после настроек не видит сервер.
Конфигурации barman:

cat /etc/barman.conf

```
; Barman, Backup and Recovery Manager for PostgreSQL
; http://www.pgbarman.org/ - http://www.2ndQuadrant.com/
;
; Main configuration file

[barman]
; System user
barman_user = barman

; Directory of configuration files. Place your sections in separate files with .conf extension
; For example place the 'main' server section in /etc/barman.d/main.conf
configuration_files_directory = /etc/barman.d

; Main directory
barman_home = /var/lib/barman

; Locks directory - default: %(barman_home)s
;barman_lock_directory = /var/run/barman

; Log location
log_file = /var/log/barman/barman.log

; Log level (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels)
log_level = INFO

; Default compression level: possible values are None (default), bzip2, gzip, pigz, pygzip or pybzip2
;compression = gzip


configuration_files_directory = /etc/barman.d

; Pre/post backup hook scripts
;pre_backup_script = env | grep ^BARMAN
;pre_backup_retry_script = env | grep ^BARMAN
;post_backup_retry_script = env | grep ^BARMAN
;post_backup_script = env | grep ^BARMAN

; Pre/post archive hook scripts
;pre_archive_script = env | grep ^BARMAN
;pre_archive_retry_script = env | grep ^BARMAN
;post_archive_retry_script = env | grep ^BARMAN
;post_archive_script = env | grep ^BARMAN

; Global retention policy (REDUNDANCY or RECOVERY WINDOW) - default empty
;retention_policy =

; Global bandwidth limit in KBPS - default 0 (meaning no limit)
;bandwidth_limit = 4000

; Immediate checkpoint for backup command - default false
;immediate_checkpoint = false

; Enable network compression for data transfers - default false
;network_compression = false

; Number of retries of data copy during base backup after an error - default 0
;basebackup_retry_times = 0

; Number of seconds of wait after a failed copy, before retrying - default 30
;basebackup_retry_sleep = 30

; Maximum execution time, in seconds, per server
; for a barman check command - default 30
;check_timeout = 30

; Time frame that must contain the latest backup date.
; If the latest backup is older than the time frame, barman check
; command will report an error to the user.
; If empty, the latest backup is always considered valid.
; Syntax for this option is: "i (DAYS | WEEKS | MONTHS)" where i is an
; integer > 0 which identifies the number of days | weeks | months of
; validity of the latest backup for this check. Also known as 'smelly backup'.
;last_backup_maximum_age =

; Minimum number of required backups (redundancy)
;minimum_redundancy = 1

; Examples of retention policies
; Retention policy (disabled)
;retention_policy =
; Retention policy (based on redundancy)
;retention_policy = REDUNDANCY 2
; Retention policy (based on recovery window)
;retention_policy = RECOVERY WINDOW OF 4 WEEKS
```

/etc/barman.d/psql10

```
[psql10]

ssh_command = ssh barman@psql10

conninfo = host=psql10 user=postgres port=5432 dbname=mydb

archiver = off ;
```

Comment: ииии где логи? Что значит видит/не видит?

Comment: 2018-12-04 14:19:29,000 [5504] barman.cli ERROR: Unknown server 'psql10'
 Вот такая запись в логе при попытке просмотреть статус сервера.

Comment: root@psql10:/# barman list-server
root@psql10:/#
Соответственно тут вывод пустой.